# What do you call the part of the basketball hoop that attaches the rim to the backboard?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I call it the neck. Is there a proper term?

Comment: I'd call it the "bracket". That includes the plate with the screw holes in it and the piece of metal between the plate and the rim. The "neck" to me would be the joining piece and would not include the mounting plate.

Comment: Good question! [Visual Dictionary](http://www.visualdictionaryonline.com/sports-games/ball-sports/basketball/backstop.php) doesn’t name it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part of the backboard that connects to the rim is know as the 'break-away' or the 'break-away rim'. It is designed to release the force from the jump and to prevent damage to the backboard and rim.

See the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakaway_rim) entry

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=break-away+rim&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5l8jyp6fiAhUBaFAKHT3CA0kQ_AUIDigB&biw=1309&bih=647 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakaway_rim

Comment: It might be a good idea to cite a reference or two, or just post an image.

Comment: Is it a break-away only if it has that folding action? Based on the name, I would assume a rigid connection would not be called a break-away? OP's question leaves it open to be about a rigid bracket, so I'd suggest mentioning that this answer only partially applies (i.e. to folding brackets).